# How to add new attribute to reportElement tag in iReports?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am trying to include css class in my reports. Is it possible to add my own attribute to reportElement tag, so that i can include my css file reference link ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need to do is add a property to the fields you are wanting referenced. To add the class name you need to add **`net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.class`** and to include an id you need to add **`net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.id`** as a property. As an example, below is a Text field that sets both:

```
<textField>
    <reportElement uuid="2399e4ef-633c-4d17-b964-3e093ece1936" x="0" y="22" width="100" height="20">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.class" value="TEST"/>
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.id" value="ID"/>
    </reportElement>
    <textElement markup="html"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{field1}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

In iReport you add these by selecting the field, and then in the properties window clicking the ellipses button next to `Properties expressions`.
[image]

To include the link to the css file in the exported report, you need to set the value for the `JRHtmlExporterParameter.HTML_HEADER` parameter before exporting. Note the parameter is not the header in the sense of HTML (the contents of the head tag), but the header of the exported HTML report. Meaning it is what is first placed in the exported report to begin with, before including the report. The default that Jasper Reports uses is:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <style type="text/css">
    a {text-decoration: none}
  </style>
</head>
<body text="#000000" link="#000000" alink="#000000" vlink="#000000">
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr><td width="50%">&nbsp;</td><td align="center">
```

So you will need to modify this to include the link to your stylesheet by adding:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<cssfile you want to point to>" />
```

to that in the appropriate place, which I think is inside the head tag, but if not move to appropriate area. So the java code would end looking something like:

```
JRHtmlExporter exporter = new JRHtmlExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.HTML_HEADER, 
    "<html>"+
    "<head>"+
    "  <title></title>"+
    "  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>"+
    "  <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"css/jasper.css\" />"+
    "  <style type="text/css">"+
    "    a {text-decoration: none}"+
    "  </style>"+
    "</head>"+
    "<body text="#000000" link="#000000" alink="#000000" vlink="#000000">"+
    "<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">"+
    "<tr><td width="50%">&nbsp;</td><td align="center">");
exporter.exportReport();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I understood the second part of your answer that is setting the html_header. I didn't understand the setting of class and id. Is it like i need to add the class and id for all the text fields. Is there a generic way to do so, because all my reports have the same style for the text field.

Comment: and also we are using jasper reports 3.7.4 where i came across only net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.id. It also doesnot support uuid tag element in reportElement. :(

Comment: @user1103504 You will more than likely need to update to a newer version of jasper reports. `net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.class` was not added until later versions. Also unfortunately I did not see a generic way to set the class or id. So it has to be done on each field when you are designing the report.